# Unmarshalling error from Soap client

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, soap-client

The WSDL part is as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="requestRow">
<xs:all>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RoutingData" type="tns:RoutingData"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="user_fields">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="user_field" type="tns:user_field"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="RoutingData">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RouteDataPoint" type="tns:RouteDataPoint"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RoutingSegmentID" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="RouteDataPoint">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="Lattitude" type="xs:double"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The intention is to allow EITHER RouteDataPoint OR RoutingSegmentID in the input, not both and also if neither is entered should throw an error. Rather when giving the following input with neither of the mentioned above, gives Unmarshalling Error with no detail.

INPUT:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:get="http://www.g1.com/services/GetRouteData">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:GetRouteDataRequest>
         <get:context>
            <get:account.id>admin</get:account.id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <get:account.password>admin</get:account.password>
         </get:context>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <get:options>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <get:DataSetResourceName>US</get:DataSetResourceName>                
         </get:options>
         <get:rows>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <get:row>
               <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
               <!--Optional:-->
               <get:RoutingData>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <get:RouteDataPoint>
                     <get:Longitude></get:Longitude>
                     <get:Lattitude></get:Lattitude>
                  </get:RouteDataPoint>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <get:RoutingSegmentID></get:RoutingSegmentID>
               </get:RoutingData>
            </get:row>
         </get:rows>
      </get:GetRouteDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error:</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Kindly help. In the BE, I have done the NULL check of the object of the corresponding JAXB class, but the code does not reach till then and throws error before itself.